# Initialization Error after any change

Tags: wordpress, database

[image]
My website has member side and after adding a member to a site the site was broken and for members, Initialization Error occurs. so members couldn't access their own page on the website. 
and also when I install the new plugin I get this error again. I couldn't change anything on the website because after adding new page or post I have this problem.
What is the reason of this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot of the error you're describing?

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot is incomplete (it's cut off on the right side) - but it looks like you have the wrong MySQL credentials somewhere.  I would look at the two DSN lines in `civicrm.settings.php` and ensure they're correct.

Comment: Thanks. But It's not the issue.Our host supporter tells us civicrm.settings.php doesn't have any problem!! And I couldn't find the reason. Could the plugins or WordPress theme be a reason for this error?

Comment: As I mentioned, it's difficult to help because your screenshot is cut off.  However, your theme/plugins can NOT be the problem.  Please confirm that you can log into MySQL using the credentials in `civicrm.settings.php`.  If your host provider is correct, there should be no problem.

Comment: Also, could you please paste the text of the error into your question and not just the screenshot?  Part of why people offer free help here is because it can help others with the same problem later.  If you don't paste the error, people can't search for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot definitely points that your MySQL connection is not correct that is defined in civicrm.settings.php file.

You can use [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to test the database connection or if you have access to phpmyadmin you can test it through there too.